# Vue v-html directive does not run <script src=".."> tags

Tags: html, ajax, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a Vue SPA app which needs to support old modules of the system.
I want to create backward-compatible components which will get a full HTML module through an ajax request and insert it inside the component.

The problem is that the excepted HTML contains relevant scripts that should be included.
is there any option to inject JS files from the server through HTML?

```
<template>
  <div class="container" v-html="html"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "comp",
  data() {
    return {
      html: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8090/api/html/response')
        .then(response => {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.html= data;
        })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use `v-html` for this because the directive simply sets an element's `innerHTML`, which does not execute `<script>` tags.

AFAIK, the only other option is to append to the document a `<script>` with the intended source, so perhaps you could create an API to fetch the scripts separate from the markup, then inject them into the `document`:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8090/api/js/response')
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(scriptUrls => {
          for (const url of scriptUrls) {
            const scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
            scriptEl.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
          }
        })
}
```